# jQuery count of checked checkboxes in datatable pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want the count of checked checkboxes in all pages(I have datatable pagination). Currently, I only have the count of checked checkboxes in the current page. When I go to second page, it goes back to zero and counts again.

Here is the code:

```
     $('[for-checkbox]').parent().find('input').on('change', function () {

    var total = 0;
    $('[for-checkbox]').parent().find('input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) total++;
    });

    if (total > 0) $('[checkbox-callback]').html(total + ' counted');
    else $('[checkbox-callback]').html('');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all pages"? Do you mean different web pages than the one currently loaded?

Comment: I have pagination in my web page. @ChrisConway

Comment: Everthing you do in javascript in the browser is only saved in the memory. When you navigate to a different `html`-page everything will reset. You can't  "save" variables between pages because everytime you go to a different page the javascript reruns and forgets it's previous session. You could use something like :https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: If multiple web pages are loaded one after the other, your JS script will be reloaded and won't remember what the previous value was. You need to save that value somewhere (cookie, localStorage, or URL query string), and before doing `var total = 0;`, check if you already have that value saved.

Comment: you'll have to store the count in the datatable/database of that particular page and then use that for all pages and count them together with every page you load in.

Comment: I actually have datatable pagination. @rymdmaskin

Comment: Alright, sorry, I missunderstood. I haven't used datatable so I can't help you there. So it can be that your `var total = 0;` is in the wrong place in the code so it's getting overwritten on pagination? Don't know how the pages are loaded. @gizemdemirel

Answer (score 1):

Is the entire html for the datatable loaded on page load? Or does it call back to the server and get new data? My guess is that the table is being reloaded from the server when you go to another page. In that case, you'll have to keep the total variable outside of your first for loop.

You'll also have to account for unchecking a checkbox and decrement the total variable.

Try something like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('[for-checkbox]').parent().find('input').on('change', function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) total++;
    else total--;

    if (total > 0) $('[checkbox-callback]').html(total + ' counted');
    else $('[checkbox-callback]').html('');
});
```